# Is it safe to store Firebase Client Tokens in plain text on my SQL server?

Tags: android, firebase, security, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an app where I'll be pushing notifications, and I wanted to make sure that I kept things as safe possible, so I wanted to ask if there would be any issue storing plain text Firebase Client Tokens.

Thanks!

Comment: You can save it encrypted and decrypt when you need to send a push notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it does not have access to the [Firebase Authorization Bearer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), even if it has your Firebase Clients Token, it can not do anything.

but it's better encrypt your tokens when you want to insert to db.